# Look for any physical sign of him - you don't want to walk right by him

Tags: meaning

**Source -** The Rescue

**Author -** Nicholas Sparks

> Look for any physical sign of him - you don't want to **walk right by** him.

**Context -**

A little boy of four years have been lost and the search team is being arranged for the search. The above quoted sentence is an instruction to the search team.

**My question -**

What is the meaning of **walk by**? Is this a phrasal verb? I haven't found it in any dictionary.

Comment: Did you check the definitions for "by"?

Answer (score 1):

"walk right by" means to pass him and not realize that it's him.

We often use this expression when someone sees us and intentionally ignores us:

> She saw me at the bar and just walked right by without saying hello.

In your example, it would be unintentional. They would miss the boy, having been right next to him.

Answer (score -2):

*Walk by* in such way is used to refer either ignorance or simply *missing* something somehow (intentionally or unintentionally). Here, the context is of **searching** the boy, so the instruction is *Watch out carefully, you should **not miss him** passing by.* The word *right* is to emphasize.

Other uses of *walk by*...

A good example of *ignorance* is [here (song)](https://community.musixmatch.com/lyrics/26875/15111827#):

> But you don't see 
>  
>   ***You don't see me***
>  
>   You don't see I'm in deep as I can be
>  
>   You don't see me, you don't see
>  
>   You don't see me
>  
>   (Bridge)
>   This is killin me and I
>  
>   Feel like telling you just why
>  
>   This can't wait
>  
>   We're wastin time
>  
>   But you walk-walk
>  
>   You walk-walk
>  
>   ***You walk right by***

An example of something being *unnoticed*

> *Ah, I always walk by that building but never knew that there's a pub!*

Comment: Note that "passing by" refers to the searchers, not the search target. And they are searching _for_ the boy, not examining his person for contraband. That's probably why you got some downvotes.